# deriving google images in iphone

Tags: iphone

I donot want to directly open a google page. I want to get only images from any site (like google images) in iphone.What should i use for it

a UITableView       or
a UIWebView       or
a UIImageView

Answer (score 1):

Use a scroll view and keep imageViews on that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UIScrollView for same. If you want then you can use [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) API for same.